# What makes Brahma muhurta special for sadhana?

Tags: sadhana

Why is brahma muhurta given so much importance? What exactly is its significance as per shastras?

I heard that at the time of brahmamuhurta all rishis on earth release their spiritual energies and hence one's sadhana is easy at that time and more beneficial.

I want to know what reason shastras give about it.

Comment: @Just_Do_It no it doesn't. It don't tell the reason for brahma muhurta being good for spiritual activities. That's the thing i want to know.

Comment: @Rudra What are the sadhanas you are referring to?